# iPhone - How to implement feedback feature directly to server

Tags: php, iphone, forms, post, get

I'm an iPhone Developer, and I've recently got into PHP.

On a website that I've recently done for someone, I made a [feedback form](http://continuumtrio.co.uk/contact.php). This submits the data to a PHP file via POST, and then my PHP codes saves it to the MySQL database. The person I made the site for can then view it on a CMS I made for them.

That's all great (and I have no problem with the PHP), but what if I wanted to do it from an iphone app (directly to the server)?

Would you make a GET request like so: http://www.mysite.com/app_data/submit_feedback.php?api_key=somekey&name=somename&email=someemail&feedback=lots%20of%20characters%20with%lots%20of%20escapes%20in

Or is it possible to submit POST data from the iPhone? Should I use ASIHTTPRequest? Or should I package the data in XML/JSON and have it upload the file somehow?

I would appreciate any advice on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ASIHttpRequest, or use the standard API NSURLConnection and NSMutableURLRequest.

You can submit POST using NSMutableURLRequest:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlEncoded]
                                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                      timeoutInterval:60];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[ requestBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

....

theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

I could go on and provide a full example, but you should just look at apples example

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Answer (score 1):

You want ASIHTTPRequest for this, particularly the ASIFormDataRequest subclass. You can load up a request with post data fields, then bang it on the server asynchronously in the background. Perfect for this kind of thing.

Lots of good sample code here:
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest